# Where is or where should be the folder following the port number in a url?

Tags: ubuntu, webserver, path

I have the following error when running an Ubuntu server using apache2 and nginx
(`index):8 GET http://157.27.222.38:5000/uv/lib/offline.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

I was wondering where `/uv/` folder should be to be seen by the server. Is this a path relative to the root path in the server configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear from your question whether you are using Apache or Nginx.  I assume it is similar for nginx, but I'll answer for Apache which I am more familiar with.

**/uv/ is typically relative to the DocumentRoot** specified in the relevant Apache VirtualHost or main config, however there are a number of exceptions to this.

- If you have a config specifying an "Alias" this can graft in a directory from another place on the filesystem.
- Similarly it is possible to use RewriteRules to force (for example) /uv/ to be parsed into index.php or similar (which is used by Wordpress and other software - but usually only in the case /uv/ does not exist.
- It is possible that ProxyPass directives will do load-balance stuff under this from other servers.

Comment: I believe the loose equivalent of Apache's DocumentRoot in NginX is "root" for the appropriate virtual container (specified by a "server" stanza and server_name".

Comment: Hi thanks a. lot for the answer! I am running nginx at port 80 and apache2 at port 1080 I am trying to run the following example https://github.com/UniversalViewer/uv-hello-world

Comment: You are missing something - the :5000 in the URL, alongside the 404 error implies there is a server running on port 5000 as well.  If you use Linux, "sudo fuser -n tcp 5000" will give you the process ID of what is listening on port 5000 and "ps PROCESSID" will give you the command associated with that process.

Comment: Looking at your code example, I expect you are running another "Web Server" on port 5000 which is neither Apache nor NGINX, rather it is an npm instance.   FWIW I installed the setup above and its prerequisites and it worked fine for me.  the "/uv/" would appear to be relative to the uv-hello-world directory the code runs from.   On my system (installed as a user, I had a directory "/home/myusername/uv-hello-world/uv" and this contained a whole lot of html, js and css code which is presumably what you are looking for).  ...

Comment: I note that I launched this as per the instructions - cd uv-hello-world; npm-install; npm-start

Comment: Thanks a lot davidgo for your efforts, so I don't understand why it doesn't work in my Linux server if this is a new server where is looking for the files that can not be found?

Comment: I don't know! How did you install and run it?  I winder if "npm install" partially failed for you?

Comment: Strange I don't have any errors during the installation I've install it in var\www\html I am managing to get it work in my local machine